# Postgres Exception 42601 syntax error while integrating hangfire .net core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, hangfire

Facing Issue while accessing dashboard hangfire.
Showing Error like
PostgresException: 42601:syntax error at or near "value" POSITION:59
Postgres Exception